# Detecting thin lines in blurry image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, opencv, filtering

[image][image]I'm looking for some ideas to detect lines in the attached image. Lines are assumed to be vertical, but their are very poor quality and there are only 2-3 pixels between each blurry line.

I tried these methods already:
Erosion& Dilation in vertical ->good result for enhancement
CLAHE -> Good for enhancement
Hough -> Failed since converting the images to Black & while will have too many broken lines or bridges.
Also I tried vertical line Mask too.
Basically methods based on Black&White image conversion won't be applicable for this.

[image: Detecting very thin lines in blurry image]

Comment: https://matlabcorner.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/recognizing-pentomino-from-scanned-paper-part-2/ - (Disclaimer - this is my own blog).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would collapse the image along the lines to get 1d profile. And do the detection there (e.g. by looking at the peaks above the median.

Here is the collapsed image [image: collapsed image]

The object detection there is obvious

Comment: Seems to be an interesting approach. How did you collapse the columns to get such a good 1d profile ?

Comment: +1. One can just use `ys = sum(I,1)`, were `I` is the grayscale image. Also, to find the maxima, you could use `findpeaks()`, maybe in combination with `smooth()` to remove noise.

Comment: Works great on this sample, but will fail if the rotation happens to cause the top and bottom to be offset relative to each other by exactly one line. You could reduce the problem by taking only a small stripe from the middle of the image.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry that approach to collapsing columns seems very likely to fail if the image is badly illuminated (or blurry, as is the case).

Comment: @mmgp I tested it with the input images, and it worked: `I = rgb2gray(imread('lrFFH.jpg')); ys = sum(I,1); [ans, loc] = findpeaks(smooth(ys)); clf; plot(ys); hold; plot(loc, ys(loc),'ro');`.

Comment: I didn't want to imply that it wouldn't work here, but that it seems to fail easily with slightly different inputs.

Comment: @mmgp collapsing the columns is exactly the way to deal with badly illuminated data because it increases the signal to noise

Comment: before posting, I already tested used only 3 horizontal stripe of the image. That already failed since the image is too blurred and also we are talking about 2-3 pixel wide lines.

Comment: Sure, @sega_sai, but that depends on how you collapse the columns. I can easily see an example where collapsing all columns results in a flat profile.

Comment: @mmgp I'm collapsing the columns by just summing, and the author explicitly said "Lines are assumed to be vertical", which is exactly the problem I was solving. If they are indeed vertical, the procedure will work for sure. If they are only slightly non-vertical, then the way to deal with it is to split the y axis into few chunks, make 1d profiles for each chunk, detect the peaks there.
But anyway I'm not pretending that the solution is 100% optimal. It does the job of solving the specified problem. I'm pretty sure it can be done differently/better.

Comment: We can only work with what the questioner provides. There is no mention of illumination, or what kind of blur except for the given examples. The solution works for those examples. Different types of input requires obviously different solutions, depending on which assumptions hold. E.g. If the peaks are closer together, remove/change the smoothing.

Comment: collapsing was a very good idea so far, Thanks. And i think for the case where there is some rotation, we have to find the rotation with another method! Do you guys think of any filtering method to enhance the quality a bit more? There's no illumination problem for this case, rotation can be discussed in another post too.

Comment: I also add another photo where this collapsing fails, though I should say it's still a good idea.

Comment: Actually, it also seems to work on the new image, except you do not need to do any smoothing: http://imgur.com/1ZkkF (zoom in). By the way, you might be interested in using FFT for filtering, but that's a different subject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317054/Simple-FFT-and-Filtering-Tutorial-with-Matlab

Comment: It works to some extent, eg. 181 lines detected instead of 170 be cause of the accumulation of noise when collapsing the image.

Comment: FFT could be useful since there's a repeated pattern in the image, though what you see here is just a part of the main image.

Comment: Collapsing is absolutely the way to go. Actually, I would use the term: "Integration along an axis". In the case where the rotation is unknown, we can use numerical optimization to find the "best angle" for the measurements that we want to make. After rotating the image, integrate along the vertical axis (of the rotated image), and use the amount of energy in the high spatial frequencies as the objective function. A quick-and-dirty way to measure this is to use the first-finite-difference as a rough-and-ready high-pass filter, with the outputs summed to give an indication of signal strength.

Comment: This approach works well in all sorts of situations where signal-to-noise ratio is low. Summation and the central limit theorem are your friends! --- may the power of big-n be with you.

Answer (score 3):

Very promising works regarding faint edges detection in noisy images:
Basic version for straight lines:
http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~meirav/EdgesGalunBasriBrandt.pdf
More advanced version:
http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~meirav/Curves_Alpert_Galun_Nadler_Basri.pdf

I'm not sure if the authors made their code publicly available. It might be worth-while contacting the authors directly.

These works proposes a well studied and principled method for faint-edge detection.

Comment: Great papers, thanks! A simple google search turns up this source code: https://java.net/projects/ixent/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/org/jvnet/ixent/algorithms/graphics/edgedetection?rev=33 It may or may not be the source code to the papers/algorithms in question. This is the homepage for the papers: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~ronen/index_files/edges.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach, that will find you the lines, assuming that the peak is apparent within ~5 pixels. It will be tolerant to small rotations of the image.

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7qMT.jpg');
img = rgb2gray(img);

%# smoothen the image a little with an anisotroic Gaussian
fimg = imfilter(double(img),fspecial('gaussian',[3 1]));

%# find the lines as local maxima
msk = ones(5);
msk(:,2:4) = 0;
lines = fimg > imdilate(fimg,msk);
```

[image]

Comment: You can then use e.g. `bwareaopen` to remove some of the spurious signals, and you can run skeletonization to make the lines 1 pixel wide.

Comment: This is a good approach for filtering. Thanks. But how would you detect such thin lines? For example in the situation where the lines in the bottom of the black area is e.g. 20% of the rest of the lines, wouldn't those be eliminated if we seek for the peaks only?

Comment: @Hamed one way I can see to proceed from here is simply by majority voting. Pick the first line, if there is a white point at position `x` then, for the moment, you say there is a vertical line passing on `x`. Repeat for every line. If at a given position `x` you get most of lines "saying" there is a white dot on `x`, then you draw a vertical passing on `x`. If you don't thin the lines (I believe Jonas misspelled this, you don't want to obtain a skeleton here) then you will possibly get multiple adjacent lines which can be easily collapsed into a single one.

Comment: @Hamed: The output here is the segmentation result. What information do you need to extract from the lines?

Comment: I actually need to retrieve lines about perfectly to reconstruct the image. Answering your question, number of lines is important too, though counting them isn't an issue if they are nicely highlighted. Thanks.