# How to detect boundaries of a pattern

Tags: image, image-processing, pattern-matching, feature-detection, edge-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting thin lines in blurry image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767850/detecting-thin-lines-in-blurry-image)

So as the title says, I am trying to detect boundaries of patterns. In the images attached, you can basically see three different patterns.

1. Close stripe lines
2. One thick L shaped line
3. The area between 1 & 2

I am trying to separate these three, in say 3 separate images. Depend on where the answers go, I will upload more images if needed. Both idea or code will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Are these the only kinds of patterns you wish to detect? Or will they change? Also, what is your programming language/platform? The available libraries will vary based on your answer.

Comment: The patterns are not changing. That is stripe lines, either vertical or horizontal. And about Libraries & language anything would be fine since I'm mainly looking for an idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Astor: There's no relation between this topic and the other one. Here I am not detecting lines or extracting. The aim is to detect regions/segments. using the proposed methods of the other topic will not be useful for detecting the 3 regions in this image for example. Am i right?

Comment: People reject what they don't understand, this is clearly not a duplicate, much less an exact duplicate. Stackoverflow is in a sad state.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve (for some values of "solve") this problem using morphology. First, to make the image more uniform, remove irrelevant minima. One way to do this is using the h-dome transform for regional minima, which suppresses minima of height < `h`. Now, we want to join the thin lines. That is accomplished by a morphological opening with a horizontal line of length `l`. If the lines were merged, then the regional minima of the current image is the background. So we can fill holes to obtain the relevant components. The following code summarizes these tasks:

```
f = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/02X9Z.jpg'));
hm = imhmin(f, h);
o = imopen(hm, strel('line', l, 0));
result = imfill(~imregionalmin(o), 'holes');
```

Now, you need to determine `h` and `l`. The parameter `h` is expected to be easier since it is not related to the scale of the input, and in your example, values in the range [10, 30] work fine. To determine `l` maybe a granulometry analysis could help. Another way is to check if the `result` contains two significant connected components, corresponding to the bigger L shape and the region of the thin lines. There is no need to increase `l` one by one, you could perform something that resembles a binary search.

Here are the `hm`, `o` and `result` images with `h = 30` and `l = 15` (`l` in [13, 19] works equally good here). This approach gives flexibility on parameter choosing, making it easier to pick/find good values.

[image] [image] [image]

To calculate the area in the space between the two largest components, we could merge them and simply count the black pixels inside the new connected component.

Comment: I really thank you for your time. My latest method was just close to yours except for imhmin part. That blew my mind!!!! BUT, what would you do if the input image is just the same with 90' rotation? Then the Horizontal lines will be emphasized on and you cannot get the same perfect result. For this question, I cannot make any assumption here about the direction of input image. Thanks.

Comment: There are ways to estimate orientation. In your case, there are simple ways to do considering the volume after an morphological closing with horizontal lines. For example, this is what I get with a line of width/2: http://i.imgur.com/GNx8u.png http://i.imgur.com/gUUrM.png. For a better view into this, consider reading "Image Structure Orientation Using Mathematical Morphology" by Soille and Talbot.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a window (10x10 pixels?) and collect features for that window. The features could be something as simple as the cumulative [gradients (edges)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) within that window. This would distinguish the various areas as long as the window is big enough.

Then using each window as a data point, you can do some clustering, or if the patterns don't vary that much you can do some simple thresholds to determine which data points belong to which patterns (the larger gradient sums belong to the small lines: more edges, while the smallest gradient sums belong to the thickest lines: only one edge, and those in between belong to the other "in-between" pattern .

Once you have this classification, you can create separate images if need be.

Comment: Thanks Noremac. Initially i though about similar method. But I noticed even though the patterns/textures are pretty constant, but the gap between the stripe lines is significantly different. In some images a window of 10x10 will include 3-4 lines but in another image it wont include even one line since the space between the gaps will be times larges. This variation applies to other parts as well. Did I understand your suggestion correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you do for the most part. If there's a reliable upper bound (the width of the largest areas) then you can at least get an edge on all of those. And if I understand your concerns correctly, there'd actually be four classes (large, medium, small, none). The varying gap between the stripe lines is what will distinguish the different areas. If there's no reasonable upper bound then this probably isn't a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out ideas. You can binarize the image and do connected component labelling. Then perform some analysis on the connected components such as width to discriminate between the regions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But using BW+Connected component will completely ruin the textures we are interested in. In the other hand, as you can see, all the mentioned regions are connected to each other. Segmentation also won't be a good idea for the same reason.